# How to add border to a container with transparent gaps in between

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

Here is an image of the design which I am trying to achieve with only CSS.

[image]

How do I achieve such border for the container div so that I can place transparent logo and text in between the gaps. This design will go on a video background. The black background is just for illustration purpose.

So far I have tried to achieve something like this as a test:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
.steps-frame-1 {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.steps-frame-1 {
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.steps-frame-1::after,
.steps-frame-1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.steps-frame-1::before {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
.steps-frame-1::after {
  border-bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps-frame-1">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>content Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddn53xsf/)

The problem is to get the gap on top border as well for the logo. Also this whole container must be responsive.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you may need more elements to build this properly.

Comment: What if you fake it with absolute positioned divs that are thin and are full colour to act as border? Have you tried that. It's the simplest solution I think.

Comment: have a look this, here background image is used http://www.guyroutledge.co.uk/blog/better-dotted-borders-with-border-image/

Comment: Are those gaps fixed size or should they grow/shrink depending on content?

Comment: Will the height be changing as well. I see you've entered 200px, so not sure if you want it to have responsive height as well.

Comment: the gaps must shrink, based on responsiveness

Comment: @MrVentzi, as i said this was just a test.. need to  add more elements as Paulie_D suggested

Comment: @manu see my revised answer. The borders will grow/shrink depending on size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use multiple `linear-gradient` images as background for the parent `div` container like shown in the below snippet. This is one way to achieve it without adding any extra elements.

The background need not be a solid color. This approach can support transparency. The only thing you would need to make note of here is that since we are using percentages in the `linear-gradient`, the gap will increase as the height/width increases (and vice-versa). You can see this by using the "Full Page" option.

The `transform: translateX(-50%), translateY(-50%)` on the text containers are for vertical and horizontal centering of the content within the space.

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
.steps-frame-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 30vw;
  width: 75vw;
  margin: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, beige 5%, transparent 5%, transparent 20%, beige 20%), linear-gradient(to bottom, beige 45%, transparent 45%, transparent 55%, beige 55%), linear-gradient(to bottom, beige 45%, transparent 45%, transparent 55%, beige 55%);
  background-size: 100% 2px, 2px 100%, 2px 100%;
  background-position: top left, top left, top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-bottom: 2px solid beige;
}
.left-text,
.right-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  color: beige;
}
.left-text {
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.right-text {
  right: 0%;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.top-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 12.5%;
  content: url(http://www.planetcassandra.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/GitHub_Logo.png);
  width: 15%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="steps-frame-1">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>content Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='top-text'></div>
  <div class='left-text'>Text</div>
  <div class='right-text'>Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. Let me try this on my design quickly and get back.

Comment: harry, your answers works perfect for me, for the text part. However i have a small issue with logo. please see the JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/f1f3zz3a/3/

i have tried to include a logo on top. This works good when there is a fixed screen size. But if i expand the screen size, it becomes messy. Any help on this please ?  :)

Comment: @manu: Is your image of fixed size (70px)? Can you do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/f1f3zz3a/4/)?

Comment: width: 155px
height: 65px

i think i can live with that, making it fixed size.

Comment: @manu: Ok, have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/f1f3zz3a/5/) the image dimensions is also responsive.

Comment: awesome, harry. You are a star.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

- Add one helper element on each side of the box.
- Place the logo/text inside the helper element.
- Use pseudo elements to add horizontal/vertical lines before and after the logo/text

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  padding: 80px;
  width: 50%;
}
/**** border helpers ****/
.border {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  /* disable these rules to understand what is going on */
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.border-t,
.border-b {
  left: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  height: 64px;
}
.border-t {
  top: 0;
}
.border-b {
  bottom: 0;
}
.border-l,
.border-r {
  top: 32px;
  bottom: 32px;
  width: 64px;
}
.border-l {
  left: 0;
}
.border-r {
  right: 0;
}
/**** logo and text ****/
.border > span {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.border-t span,
.border-b span {
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}
.border-l span,
.border-r span {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
/**** lines ****/
.border span::before,
.border span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
/**** lines (horizontal) ****/
.border-t span::before,
.border-b span::before,
.border-t span::after,
.border-b span::after {
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 999px;
}
.border-t span::before,
.border-b span::before {
  right: 100%;
}
.border-t span::after,
.border-b span::after {
  left: 100%;
}
/**** lines (vertical) ****/
.border-l span::before,
.border-r span::before,
.border-l span::after,
.border-r span::after {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  height: 999px;
}
.border-l span::before,
.border-r span::before {
  bottom: 100%;
}
.border-l span::after,
.border-r span::after {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus bibendum finibus ligula sit amet gravida. Sed scelerisque dapibus tempus.</p>
    <p>Curabitur ipsum dui, facilisis at interdum et, feugiat eget tortor. Nunc sodales diam nec nunc sollicitudin, non blandit diam lacinia.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-t"><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/64/abstract/8/"></span></div>
  <div class="border border-b"><span></span></div>
  <div class="border border-l"><span>Integer rhoncus nunc dui, eget.</span></div>
  <div class="border border-r"><span>Curabitur quis mauris eros. In hac habitasse.</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ddn53xsf/2/)**

html

```
<div class="steps-frame-1">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>content Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.</p>
        <div class="one">text</div>
        <div class="two">text</div>
        <div class="three">text</div>
        <div class="four">text</div>
    </div>
    <!-- inner -->
</div>
```

css

```
body {
    background: black;
}
p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px;
}
.steps-frame-1 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.inner div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.one {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    left: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.two {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.three {
    top: -15px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.four {
    bottom: -15px;
    margin: auto;
    right: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The background will not be single colour so you can't really make this illusion in this case. He said "This design will go on a video background".

Comment: Yes, everything here is transparent, there is not background color for any div.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a native way to cut borders, so you have to give the illusion that it is a border with more containers.

Something like this should suffice. Nothing fancy, so browser support won't be an issue either:

```css
body {
    background: black;
}
p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px;
}
.steps-frame-1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.borderColour {
     background-color: #fff;   
}
.borderTopLeft {
     position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height:2px;
}
.borderTopRight {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height:2px;
}
.borderRightTop {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height:2px;
}
.borderRightTop {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 45%;
}
.borderRightBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height:45%;
}
.borderLeftTop {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 45%;
}
.borderLeftBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height:45%;
}
.borderBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps-frame-1">
    <div class="borderColour borderTopLeft"></div>
    <div class="borderColour borderTopRight"></div>
    <div class="borderColour borderRightTop"></div>
    <div class="borderColour borderRightBottom"></div>
    <div class="borderColour borderLeftTop"></div>
    <div class="borderColour borderLeftBottom"></div>
    <div class="borderColour borderBottom"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>content Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- inner -->
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddn53xsf/3/