# CSS : add space in border corner

Tags: html, css

I want to add white space in top left border square's bottom right corner. currently my code return full square border. but I want space in border corners like attached image.
[image]
Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-left-corner"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-left-corner{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
```

**Here is Fiddle**
[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/pz7rcg4u/)

```css
.top-left-corner {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left-corner">
</div>
```

Comment: In top left (or) bottom right? In your image it looks like bottom right. (Not a duplicate but the answers in this thread should give you the idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205386/how-to-add-border-to-a-container-with-transparent-gaps-in-between/31205824#31205824)

Comment: yes, that corner is place on page's top-left corner but I want border on bottom right. thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using the `before` and `after` pseudo selectors:

```css
.top-left-corner {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

.top-left-corner:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:20px; /*change this for the size of the gap*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
}

.top-left-corner:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:20px;     /*change this for the size of the gap*/
  border-right: 1px solid #7a7a7a;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left-corner"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like this (if you know the colour of the background behind your square - https://jsfiddle.net/pz7rcg4u/3/

```
.top-left-corner:after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom:-1px;
right: -1px;
z-index: 1;
height: 10px; /* size of white space */
width: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #F3F5F6;
border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F5F6; /* color of white space */
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need :)