# CSS - Border Breaking (without absolutely positioned elements)

Tags: html, css, border, border-layout

Pictures below should depict what I'm looking for.

I've got a div with text and a button inside; this div has a 2px border all the way around in white.  Behind this div is a section that contains a background image.  I want to position the text over the side and bottom of the border so that the border breaks (but also continues to show the background image below).

Is this possible without absolutely positioning 6 lines around the edges of this div?

[image: Example of what I mean]

Comment: By default using just the `border` property, no. However could whip it up pretty quick with SVG.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205386/how-to-add-border-to-a-container-with-transparent-gaps-in-between) is a really good answer.  It uses multiple `linear-gradient`'s to create the border.  Pay attention to the `background-image` property of `.steps-frame-1`

Comment: @lamelemon - Thanks so much for this resource; exactly what I need and that makes perfect sense. =)  I searched for hours before posting this, so I really appreciate you finding this.  Hoping this approach won't take me as long as absolutely positioning 6 individual lines for each box.

Comment: @Picasso-ITS if you have any issues, post your code up and I can try to help you out.