# How to create a custom border with a gap?

Tags: css, border

I need to create a top border around a top that leaves a partial gap. Something such as:

```
 ____________________________    (gap)      __________________________
|                                                                     |
|                                                                     |
```

The gap I'm trying to create is on the TOP (ignore the ones on the side, that's just to emphasize it's a div). The gap may or may not be perfectly centered -- in other words, it may vary where the gap exists.

Is it possible to do this with css?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205386/how-to-add-border-to-a-container-with-transparent-gaps-in-between/31205824#31205824

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element absolutely positioned in your container with a background color that matches whatever the background of your page is.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer has one flaw, if one want the gap to be "transparent" on top of its background, it won't work if the background is not a solid color.

So to do it on any background, like images, gradient etc., use both pseudo elements, like this:

*By altering each pseudo element's width one control both where the gap will be, and its size.*

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow);
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 45vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
div::before, div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
div::before {
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
}
div::after {
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

And for anyone who need at text in the gap, here's how-to.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow);
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 45vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
div::before, div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
div::before {
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
}
div::after {
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

div span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
div span {
  left: 20%;
}
div span {
  right: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Hello</span></div>
```

Comment: This solution worked better for my situation than the accepted answer. One change I did was to use border instead of background for the pseudo elements. I also expanded the height of the pseudo elements. I did so because the border in my case was in my site header, and I needed the border to span two elements vertically. In other words, in the main div, I needed two lines to converge at the top corner, rather than display a single horizontal line.